# Sequential and Parallel process order

Tags: ssas, ssis

What is the difference between Sequential and Paralle Process Order in Analysis Services Process Task, in SSIS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's an article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966525.aspx#ECAA) that answers your question.  Parallel processing allows the server to process cubes, measure groups, and partitions in parallel.  This requires spinning off threads on separate processors which can impact general server performance.  If your server is already hurting when you process changes to the cube, then consider using Sequential.